# Mutli-Language support using Simple Keyboard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, react-simple-keyboard

I am new to vue js and is trying to implement https://virtual-keyboard.js.org/vuejs/

I have implemented the basic layout but need to do multi-languagehttps://github.com/simple-keyboard/simple-keyboard-layouts support using different language layouts as mentioned.

But I can't shift between languages. I can't actually find a way to inject different language files.

```js
<template>
  <div :class="keyboardClass"></div>
</template>

<script>
import Keyboard from "simple-keyboard";
import "simple-keyboard/build/css/index.css";
// import SimpleKeyboardLayouts from "../lib/components/Layouts";

export default {
  name: "SimpleKeyboard",
  props: {
    keyboardClass: {
      default: "simple-keyboard",
      type: String,
    },
    input: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  data: () => ({
    keyboard: null,
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.keyboard = new Keyboard(this.keyboardClass, {
      onChange: this.onChange,
      onKeyPress: this.onKeyPress,
    });
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(input) {
      this.$emit("onChange", input);
    },
    onKeyPress(button) {
      this.$emit("onKeyPress", button);

      /**
       * If you want to handle the shift and caps lock buttons
       */
      if (button === "{shift}" || button === "{lock}") this.handleShift();
    },
    handleShift() {
      let currentLayout = this.keyboard.options.layoutName;
      let shiftToggle = currentLayout === "default" ? "shift" : "default";

      this.keyboard.setOptions({
        layoutName: shiftToggle,
      });
    },
    handleLanguages() {
      let currentLayoutlang = this.keyboard.options.layoutName;
      let languageToggle =
        currentLayoutlang === "english" ? "german" : "english";
      this.keyboard.setOptions({
        layoutName: languageToggle,
      });
    },
  },
  watch: {
    input(input) {
      this.keyboard.setInput(input);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped></style>
```

A sample layout language file which I have is like

```js
import { LayoutItem } from "../interfaces";

/**
 * Layout: German
 */
export default <LayoutItem>{
  layout: {
    default: [
      "^ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 \u00DF \u00B4 {bksp}",
      "{tab} q w e r t z u i o p \u00FC +",
      "{lock} a s d f g h j k l \u00F6 \u00E4 # {enter}",
      "{shift} < y x c v b n m , . - {shift}",
      ".com @ {space}",
    ],
    shift: [
      '\u00B0 ! " \u00A7 $ % & / ( ) = ? ` {bksp}',
      "{tab} Q W E R T Z U I O P \u00DC *",
      "{lock} A S D F G H J K L \u00D6 \u00C4 ' {enter}",
      "{shift} > Y X C V B N M ; : _ {shift}",
      ".com @ {space}",
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you please give me the link of this project's git repo?. I am working on a same project so I'll clone your repo. It will save a lot of my time.

Comment: https://github.com/V5NEXT/Mutli-language-Keyboard  ... Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the `simple-keyboard-layouts`, and then do this in your `method` where you want to change the language:

```
handleLanguages() {
  let languageToggle =
    this.keyboard.options.layoutName === "english" ? "german" : "english";
  const layout = new this.SimpleKeyboardLayouts().get(languageToggle);
  this.keyboard.setOptions({ layout });
}
```

That is how you can toggle languages using this library. If it is missing a language you need then throw up a PR in the [simple-keyboard-layouts](https://github.com/simple-keyboard/simple-keyboard-layouts), I've found the author to be very responsive and helpful with the layouts I've added.

[Here is a fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-simple-keyboard-layouts-language-switcher-xn9s5?file=/src/SimpleKeyboard.vue:0-1722) (you may need to click the refresh icon within the fiddle for the button to show up), note some of the newer versions of `simple-keyboard-layouts` seem to not work with this functionality, so be sure to check the `package.json` for version numbers that are compatible or update your code to match whatever the latest and greatest is from this library. These are the versions that definitely *do* work for this:

```
"simple-keyboard": "^2.32.108",
"simple-keyboard-layouts": "^1.15.165",
```

Comment: I did the same but it's failing to import layouts. npm install simple-keyboard-layouts --save ...

import SimpleKeyboardLayouts from "simple-keyboard-layouts";
And also from where should I use SimpleKeyboardLayouts() you added at the function

Comment: Please see the code at https://github.com/V5NEXT/Vue-Keyboard

Comment: @V5NEXT instead of using all of `SimpleKeyboardLayouts` it sounds like you only need German? Perhaps just try this `import layout from "simple-keyboard-layouts/build/layouts/german";` and then `this.keyboard.setOptions({layout})`

Comment: That didn't work, the keyboard just collapses since there is no value, and what I planned to do is to toggle between the languages not just German

Comment: @V5NEXT can you create a fiddle of this?

Comment: There are multiple components and I am completely new to Vue.
https://jsfiddle.net/VishnuV5NEXT/12rgfav4/1/

Comment: @V5NEXT I created a fiddle for you. Please check your `package.json` version numbers for `simple-keyboard` and `simple-keyboard-layouts` as the newer versions either changed the API or have a bug. These versions work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-field-3dsmp?file=/src/SimpleKeyboard.vue

Comment: @V5NEXT also you may need to click the refresh icon to refresh the fiddle after it loads so that the "Switch Layout to German" button shows up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237103/discussion-between-v5next-and-maxshuty).

Comment: Updated fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-simple-keyboard-layouts-language-switcher-xn9s5?file=/src/SimpleKeyboard.vue:0-1722